# Possible RMAN orphan files in backup directory

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, backup, rman

I am trying to scrape together some space in my Oracle 11g backup directory in AIX.  I have deleted obsolete files using RMAN's "DELETE OBSOLETE" command, but I see many (just under 200) files dated from over two months ago although my backup policy should only be retaining backups for two days.  Here is a sample:

```
-rw-r-----    1 oracle   oinstall 21342912512 Sep 09 03:02 v1pi0pe8_1_1
-rw-r-----    1 oracle   oinstall 8866766848 Sep 09 07:23 v2pi0pe9_1_1
-rw-r-----    1 oracle   oinstall 13993369600 Sep 09 01:29 v3pi0pe9_1_1
-rw-r-----    1 oracle   oinstall 11262451712 Sep 09 00:16 v4pi0pe9_1_1
-rw-r-----    1 oracle   oinstall    1402368 Sep 08 19:15 v5pi0qa2_1_1
-rw-r-----    1 oracle   oinstall    1058304 Sep 08 19:45 v7pi0s2i_1_1
-rw-r-----    1 oracle   oinstall   42467840 Nov 22 22:41 v7po9ir3_1_1
-rw-r-----    1 oracle   oinstall   52970496 Nov 22 22:41 v8po9ir3_1_1
-rw-r-----    1 oracle   oinstall    1512448 Sep 08 20:15 v9pi0tqi_1_1
-rw-r-----    1 oracle   oinstall    9109504 Sep 08 20:45 vbpi0vj0_1_1
-rw-r-----    1 oracle   oinstall    1568256 Sep 08 21:15 vdpi11b4_1_1
-rw-r-----    1 oracle   oinstall  113734144 Nov 23 22:55 vepoc80o_1_1
-rw-r-----    1 oracle   oinstall    1021440 Sep 08 21:45 vfpi133g_1_1
-rw-r-----    1 oracle   oinstall   11592704 Sep 08 22:15 vhpi14rj_1_1
-rw-r-----    1 oracle   oinstall    1103360 Sep 08 22:45 vjpi16jv_1_1
-rw-r-----    1 oracle   oinstall    1811968 Sep 08 23:15 vlpi18c8_1_1
-rw-r-----    1 oracle   oinstall    1074176 Sep 08 23:45 vnpi1a4b_1_1
-rw-r-----    1 oracle   oinstall    1503744 Sep 09 00:15 vppi1bsh_1_1
-rw-r-----    1 oracle   oinstall    1081856 Sep 09 00:45 vrpi1dkr_1_1
-rw-r-----    1 oracle   oinstall    1534976 Sep 09 01:15 vtpi1fd4_1_1
-rw-r-----    1 oracle   oinstall    1088512 Sep 09 01:45 vvpi1h5e_1_1
```

Is there a way to clean up the old files?  (You can see there are some current files there also.  Those need to stay.)  I cannot find a way to tell whether they are needed for restores, although I don't know why they would be.  I have run crosschecks and everything seems OK.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe those files are not cataloged by RMAN? I would CATALOG them and then DELETE OBSOLETE once again.

Comment: +1 it's a good idea to let rman handle the deletion. So you avoid to delete files that are needed by rman erroneously.

Comment: Thanks!  Cataloging the files and re-deleting the obsolete files did the trick.  (I was under the impression it could only be done if there was a recovery catalog set up, but it is valid for any repository.)

For the record -- and for Google visitors -- using statements like this in RMAN was all I needed:
CATALOG BACKUPPIECE '/backup/lawtest/2epi2vtg_1_1';

Cataloging all the files and running DELETE OBSOLETE freed up a good bit of space.

Also, a thousand blessings upon Notepad++ and its macro facility.

Comment: @Silverlock Do you know you could use CATALOG START WITH '/path/to/dir/wit/backups/'? It will catalog all the files in path, excluding ones that already in catalog. Just a thought :)

Comment: I did not know about CATALOG START WITH . . .

I ended up using it just now in a different context.  Thanks!